# Displaying list elements horizontally with angular-bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui, angular-bootstrap

With reference to this link http://jsfiddle.net/jenniferperrin/9sCME/ I implemented the following in my MVC application.

```
<ol class="rectangle-list">
  <li ng-repeat="item in freightlist" class="info"> 
    <a href="#"> {{item.link}} </a>
  </li>
</ol>
```

This is working fine but if I try to place more another tag say `<span>` so that I can display other properties too like the following

```
 <a href="#">{{item.link}} </a> <span>{{item.name}}</span> <span> {{item.city}}</span>
```

It's not working correctly as shown in the link I mentioned above it's displaying the contents as it is line by line.

Need help to overcome this.

Comment: What is the error message that you got?

Comment: @LVarayut no error messages but it's rendering the elements line by line

Comment: Can you put your code on Jsfiddle?

Comment: @LVarayut http://jsfiddle.net/Esg5F/ this sample works a bit ok when when I try it's getting displayed as text line by line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it has nothing to do with `Angular` or `Bootstrap`. The result is rendered line by line because you applied `display: block` to the `<a>` tag:

```
.rounded-list a {
    display: block;
    ...
}
```

If you removed it out, it will display side by side as you wish. Here is the [result on JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Esg5F/1/).

Comment: I want a kind of grid row displayed in the place of `List Item` can you help me out

Comment: I'm not sure what you really want. However, if you want to use Grid row, it would be better to use it with `<div>` tag instead of `<ul>`. This would be your example [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Esg5F/3/). See more detail on [Grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid).